# Scala For loop to Higher Order Function

Tags: scala, list, higher-order-functions

I have a list of books:

```
case class Book(name:String,authors:List[String])

val books:List[Book] = List(
                 Book(name="Code in Scala",authors=List("Viny","Vinay")),
                 Book(name="Dance in 30 days",authors=List("Namratha","Namitha")),
                 Book(name="Cook in 30 days",authors=List("Pavan")),
                 Book(name="Gym in 30 days",authors=List("Nisanth","Vinay"))
                 )
```

Now i want to know the books where author name starts with "Vin".
I have implemented this in for loop like below:

```
for(b<-books ; a <- b.authors ; if a.startsWith("Vin")) yield b.name
```

But i am unable to implement this with higher order function.
I tried as below:

```
books flatMap (b=> b.authors.withFilter(a=>a.startsWith("Vin")).map(x=>x))
```

This gets me the Name of the authors but i am unable to access the book object.how can i resolve this?
Main goal here is to convert/translate the "for loops" into higher order functions(flatmap/filter/map)

Comment: If you would remove name attribute from the second code example you will get book object. Could you show your code try with higher  order function ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the translation of a for-comprehension to combinators (`map`, `flatmap` and `filter` (`withFilter`)).

You were almost there. The missing piece is accessing the book object through the right scope:

```
books.flatMap(b => b.authors.withFilter(a => a.startsWith("Vin")).map(_ => b.name))
```

The rules are explained in the [Scala language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) (pp 89 of the doc, 97 of the pdf-)

Answer (score 1):

Just change the last `map` to return what you want:

`books flatMap (b => b.authors.withFilter(a => a.startsWith("Vin")).map(_ => b.name))`

Answer (score 0):

I think the `flatMap` is unnecessary here:

```scala
scala> books.filter(_.authors.exists(_.startsWith("Vin"))).map(_.name)
res4: List[String] = List(Code in Scala, Gym in 30 days)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer ,but i was looking at how we can implement/translate the for loop logic into higher order function(map/flatmap/filter) only.This was part of a coursera course.On second thoughts your solutions also uses higher order functions only.

Comment: I don't think you can write code using higher-order functions **only**. You always need some first-order functions, what would you pass to the higher-order functions otherwise?